# Rest API testing with JGiven

Tags: jgiven

I am quite new to JGiven and currently I have a set of REST API tests automated using Rest Assured and TestNG framework. I am also exploring JGiven as a framework to run the API tests for the advantages it gives with the human readable given when thens and the reports that it generates too. Rest Assured as a library lets us inject the URLs and actually make the REST calls. I want to understand if we have such capabilities within JGiven to actually make the REST calls. If so, I'd like to see an example and understand how I can do that. If not, can someone kindly advice and suggest the best way to achieve it with JGiven. I've been trying to search for this information but have struggled to do so thus far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGiven is useful for creating test scenarios that are understandable by domain experts. It is a general tool that can be used for any kind of testing, including testing REST APIs. JGiven adds an understandable layer on top of your underlying test infrastructure. However, you will typically need tools in addition to JGiven to implement the underlying layer. So for testing REST APIs you will use a tool like Rest Assured in combination with JGiven. With JGiven you describe your scenario in the domain language, with Rest Assured you will execute the REST calls.